# Name of the 90's show/episode with a companion/sex robot (blonde, maybe Jenna McCarthy)

Tags: story-identification

A companion robot and an astronaut are returning home, and the companion robot is annoyed because the astronaut won't have sex with her. They are in a ship, and the astronaut keeps talking about his wife. This was probably mid to late 90's. I just remember having to turn it off because my parents came home. I think she was blonde, and in a tight dress in the beginning, and the guy was in his uniform. It was very, "outer limits" like, in that it wasn't an on going show, but an episode from a sci-fi series.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anything that you may remember? If you haven't already also be sure to take the [tour]!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sounds like it might be the episode [Boxed In](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0673526/?ref_=ttep_ep3) from the 1997 TV anthology "Perversions of Science." This is described as:

> Anthology series of sci-fi stories in the style of "Tales from the Crypt".

I remember the episode you are talking about as it had William Shatner in it (who also directed).

It has all the elements you mention as to a pilot, companion robot, etc.

> Sex farce about a horny faithful space ace who, after several years, finally arrives home for a tryst with his fiancee. Unfortunately, her admiral dad forces them to wait until marriage, so the pilot decides to use a sexbot. Big mistake.

Comment: Beichst, I just looked it up on youtube. You are 100% correct. You have succeeded where my dozens of hours of internet searches failed. You have completed a broken piece of my childhood. I can't explain how amazing it is going to be to finish this episode. I salute you.

Comment: Great to hear this was it. Glad I could help.

Comment: Heather Elizabeth Parkhurst, not Jenny Mccarthy, but an easy mistake to make.